# What type of dielectric materials used to make capacitors/supercapacitors?

Tags: capacitor, supercapacitor

I wonder what type of dielectric materials do the producers use to make capacitors/supercapacitors ?

Comment: What did your research tell you?

Comment: Kitiara - Welcome to EE.SE :-) There's a huge range of possible answers, depending on what level of detail you expect and how you are going to use the answer. Therefore, as expected for a [good question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) here, please explain your research so far (e.g. why wasn't [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_types) enough for you?) and give some context about why you are asking & how you plan to use any answers that you receive.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor#Materials

Comment: @SamGibson Wikipedia isn't a reliable source. I just wonder what type of dielectric materials used in the capacitors often. It may depend on getting the best results out of a capacitor with lowest price to produce. It's more like a general question.

Comment: Why do you think this site will be more reliable than Wikipedia? You didn't answer Harry's comment.

Comment: @Kitiara - "*Wikipedia isn't a reliable source*" Notice that in my comment, that was an *example* of the type of research you could (and should) do. The lack of reliability of Wikipedia articles is debatable, depending on the topic, since some of them are edited by the same people who give answers here! Also, there are capacitor manufacturer's web sites containing lots of background information too. However the lack of specific details of the research done so far, is enough info.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because plenty of information is available with a web search.

Comment: @Kitiara If you don't want to rely on wiki, use it's references as a starting point in your search. Alternatively, start searching with something like Google Scholar. e.g. https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=supercapacitor+dielectric&btnG=

Answer (score 1):

Insulators with high [dielectric constant](https://www.britannica.com/science/dielectric-constant) and high [dielectric strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_strength)